# re.match('z', 'az') returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x

See title. The behavior here is counterintuitive. I think maybe I am missing some flags or something? Why does the regex `z` not match the string `az`?

Comment: That is correct 'z' does not match with 'az'. If you say '.z' i.e. `<any character> z`  then it matches with 'az' lile `re.match(r'.z', 'az')`

Comment: Your account is over 11 years old and you have 51(!) gold badges, so you ought to know by now that [some research is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before asking here. In this case, it's as simple as looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.match) (which is [easy to find](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+re+module)); not only is the specific problem called out in the documentation for `re.match`, but it explicitly tells you what you wanted to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `match` only matches the beginning of a string. Must use `search` to do the thing that `match` would do in all other programming languages.

Sorry to throw shade at you Python, but you're the odd one out here.

Comment: Messes me up every time. . . .

Comment: Given that you've answered your own question here and used language like "throw shade", it comes across like your question and answer are really a thinly disguised rant. Please [do not use Stack Overflow for this purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), even given that it's okay to answer your own questions. Design decisions are made for a reason, and naming things is hard. Python's names make more sense to me.